# Need help sorting an array from a structure using qsort

Tags: c, qsort

I am learning to use qsort and it seems that I can't find a way to sort alphabetically the names of 'n' people using qsort.

I tried many ways, but most of them give me the same "expression must have class type" error.

```
struct ppl {
    char name[50];
};

ppl vpers[100];

void read_name(ppl* vpers, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        cout << "Name: ";
        cin >> vpers[i].name;
    }
}

void print_name(ppl * vpers, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        cout << vpers[i].name << endl;
    }
}

int compare(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    struct vpers* x = (struct vpers*)a.name;
    const struct vpers* y = (struct vpers*)b.name;    

    if ((struct vpers*)x < (struct vpers*)y) return -1;
    if ((vpers*)x == (vpers*)y) return 0;
    if ((vpers*)x > (vpers*)y) return 1;

    return(*(int*)a - *(int*)b);    
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "Nr. ppl = ";
    cin >> n;

    ppl* vpers = new ppl[n];

    read_name(vpers, n);
    print_name(vpers, n);

    qsort(vpers, n, sizeof(ppl), compare);

    print_name(vpers, n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `struct vpers* x = (struct vpers*)a.name;` is wrong. `a` is a `void*` and you're trying to access `name` on it. You need to do:  `((ppl*)a)->name;` Same thing for `b`. Also use `strcmp` to compare the names..

Comment: This is C++, not C; the tag is inaccurate.  In C++, one should use `std::sort` instead.